# Execute query & echo it in php

Tags: php, html, image, display

I am beginner in PHP, please help me find the solution of this problem. When a user types his id number i could not make it right to show his image which is stored in the database; here is the code i am using :

```
if ($pass==$dbpass&&$id== $dbid) {

 $queryimage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE `id`='$id' "))[0];

echo $queryimage;


        @$_SESSION['id']=$id;
    }
```

Comment: First don't use Mysql extension, is deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead. Second, if you want a single result like your query, fetching an array is a bad idea. You should use mysql_fetch_row in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and embed it in your code

```
$query = "SELECT images FROM attestation WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
if($result){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row[0];
}else{
    echo "No data found";
}
```

Comment: It displays only lines of weird symbols

Comment: do you want to display the image or the url of the image ?

Comment: Actually, i have stored attestations in the database..and i want when the user wants to see his attestation..it is sufficient to type his id code .. and it displays it ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if ($pass==$dbpass&&$id== $dbid) {

$queryimage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `images` FROM `attestation` WHERE id='$id' "))[0];

echo $queryimage;


    @$_SESSION['id']=$id;
}
```

i removed quotes from id after WHERE clause. i hope this will work.

Enjoy!

Comment: The same thing dear friend NedyDev... it displays only symbols